# Dealing with teselated models

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, import, faces

So I've been modelling Kylo Ren's lightsaber on **solidworks** to later make a render in **Blender**.

The problem is that when I export the model into blender in **.stl** format it has been teselated, which means that I can´t really apply any modifiers 
or smooth shading and makes it look kind of bad.

Using the remesh modifier doesn´t help because its a really complex model.

Do any of you have any advise?

Thanks.
[image: Render]
[image: Teselation]

Comment: "*Do any of you have any advice*?" Model it with [proper topology](http://topologyguides.com)  from the start if you plan to use subdivision based techniques and modifiers

Comment: Maybe AutoSmooth or EdgeSplit will help for Smooth Shading otherwise read again @DuarteFarrajotaRamos comment.

Comment: Modeling a mesh with good topology is an art form in and of itself. I'd recommend modeling inside of Blender with attention to topology from the beginning. Salvaging a bad mesh is extremely difficult and usually harder than making it correctly from nothing.